# Adding sliding menu (left drawer) to my storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

So I was creating a app using TabBarController as my main means of navigation till now but to add more options and navigation options, I wish to add a Sliding Menu/Drawer with a button on Nav bar or by swipe gesture.

I found quite a few libraries to do this but decided to go with ECS since it supports storyboard
https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

My current storyboard looks like this

[image: Storyboard]

My Tabbar was my initial viewcontroller till now and Home VC is the first screen that shows up

Any help will be appreciated, please see if you can post me code examples on how to do it aswell, kinda still new to ObjC

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: @EngrAnum to be exact, I am not sure how to implement this or any such library in my existing project which already has navigation and rootViewControllers, etc. I know the way to do is similar to how the docs of those libraries mention and probably only diff would be 2-3 lines but I am not able to get how to do it